# How to deploy a Spring Boot (Executable Jar) to Azure App Service

Tags: azure, spring-boot, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

The problem is that currently Azure offers support for deployment of a WAR file into Tomcat.  Spring Boot does support deployment via a WAR, however this negates some of the benefits of using Spring Boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that you need a way to communicate to the service what you are trying to run.  This can be handled by adding a `web.config` to the site\wwwroot folder of the app service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <httpPlatform processPath="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"
        arguments="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dserver.port=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -jar &quot;%HOME%\site\wwwroot\@project.artifactId@-@project.version@.jar&quot;">
        </httpPlatform>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

To keep the web.config out of the `src` I prefer to place it under {project root}/wwwroot

Using Maven you can add the following and get a project / release dynamically included on package.

```
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/wwwroot</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <targetPath>${basedir}/target</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
```

Now place the `jar` file and the `web.config` within the Azure App Service.

If you are using VSTS you will need 3 tasks

Task 1: Stop the Azure App

Task 2: FTP or SSH to upload the `jar` and `web.config` to the App Service

Task 3: Start the App Service.

Comment: Works without spring.profiles.active. After defining spring.profiles.active the spring boot app restarts on every request, thus is unavailble :(  ..Log has no errors..Any ideas?

Comment: You can take a look at the application logs, that might provide a hint.  Should not matter that you are using Profiles.  Keep in mind that Maven is processing this file.  If you have special char then that could cause an issue.

Comment: Make sure that you use binary mode when transferring the JAR and ascii when transferring the web.config via FTP.  If you don't you're files will be corrupt and you may see an Error Code = '-2147023829' in your eventlog.xml in Kudu.

Answer (score 0):

Add web.config under wwwroot folder, in web.config mention your jar name. Once done, upload the required jar to same folder. To upload it via FTP you need to first set the credentials under Credentials blade under AppService in Azure